# How do I automatically wrap text inside LaTeX tables produced by pandas.to_latex()?

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I am using `pandas.DataFrame.to_latex()` to automatically turn a text-filled `pd.DataFrame` into a `LaTeX` table. Everything seems fine but if the text is long, it is not broken. Using

```
longtable = True
```

does not help. Here are my settings

```python
df.to_latex(multicolumn = True, header = True, index_names = False, 
            index = False, longtable = True)
```

Comment: There is a parameter 'column_format' that allows to issue a standard latex tabular header. Thus you just have to issue a p{<desired witdh>} on columns that you wish to format as a paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LaTeX tables you control the column formats of a table with the `{table spec}` argument like this

```
\begin{tabular}[pos]{table spec}
```

The [`pandas.DataFrame.to_latex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html) can pass a format string to this argument with the `column_format` parameter. If you want to have fixed with of two columns, use e.g.

```
column_format='p{3.5cm}|p{5cm}'
```

Here is a short example illustrating how to utilize this to fix a problem comparable to yours:

```
import pandas as pd
import string

# Creating mock data
data_lower = string.ascii_lowercase
data_lower = ' '.join(data_lower[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(data_lower), 3))
# >>> abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
data_upper = string.ascii_uppercase
data_upper = ' '.join(data_upper[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(data_upper), 3))
# >>> ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR STU VWX YZ

df = pd.DataFrame({'this is a long entry in the table in minuscules':
                    data_lower,
                   'THIS IS A LONG ENTRY IN THE TABLE IN MAJUSCULES':
                    data_upper}, index=[0])

df.to_latex(multicolumn=True, header=True, index_names=False,
              index=False, column_format='p{3.5cm}|p{5cm}')
```

This gives

```latex
\begin{tabular}{p{3.5cm}|p{5cm}}
    \toprule
    this is a long entry in the table in minuscules & THIS IS A LONG ENTRY IN THE TABLE IN MAJUSCULES \\
    \midrule
    abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz & ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR STU VWX YZ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

and breaks the lines in the table at 3.5cm and 5cm respectively

[image]

if you remove the `column_format='p{3.5cm}|p{5cm}'` parameter you'll end up in too long cell entries of the latex table, what I believe is your problem.